# Strange network issue; works on windows, but not on ubuntu, works on campus wireless, but not at home

Tags: wireless, broadcom, dns

I have a broadcom device using dell laptop that can dual boot into windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have no trouble connecting to the internet using the Windows 7 side, but on Ubuntu firefox and chrome both hang on loading on startup for a bit and then give me the "webpage is not available" page with this error and some suggestions at the end:

```
The server at google.com can't be found, because the DNS
 lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's
 name to its internet access.
```

I can however use terminal and ping 8.8.8.8 successfully.

Oddly enough, when I'm on campus/ in my work building I can access the internet just fine through ubuntu and windows 7. Which leads me to believe it is some issue with my wireless router or my network configuration.

I have a LINKSYS WRT54GL. 1 other laptop and ipad that can successfully use wireless, a wired PC also connected to the router. My router setup uses DHCP with a cable modem.

I have tried using these commands related to DNS with no luck ;

```
/etc/init.d/dns-clean restart

/etc/init.d/networking force-reload

sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean
```

Also for some additional perspective; 
I could use wireless just fine at home on the ubuntu side up until about 1-2 weeks ago when I started having this problem. I also use a VPN app to connect to my work's network.  I can't recall doing anything differently from the past 1-2 weeks. The only changes I can remember are running the usual updates that Ubuntu prompts me with through update manager.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolv.conf was probably changed for VPN use and was not changed back for normal use as a result of the crash. Deleting the old resolv.conf may help. You can make a backup copy of the file and delete the original with this single command:

```
sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/backup.resolv.conf
```

A new resolv.conf will be generated as and when needed. See the answer to the following question:

[Internet connection not working although it says it is connected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164342/internet-connection-not-working-although-it-says-it-is-connected)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! It worked, however the file was named resolv.conf and not resolve.conf. Nonetheless thanks for the help, do you think this can be avoided as long as I always turn off the VPN before shutting down?

Comment: You are welcome. I corrected the errors. Please mark the answer as accepted. This will close the issue and help others to find the right answer when they search for similar problem.