# Wireless connects but cannot go to any web site; windows works fine

Tags: wireless, networking, dns

Ubu 14.04.1 x64
Broadcom wireless adapter
I came to my home office this morning and connected to the wireless network there, which I've done in the past without issue (but I was on 12.04 then) but this time I cannot connect to the internet.  I have dual boot with Windows set up, and am having no issues there.

I did some troubleshooting and can ping IP addresses (e.g., google's 8.8.8.8, and others), so I am suspecting a DNS issue.  When I compare IP configs for my Windows vs. my Ubuntu, all the settings appear identical - including the DNS Server IP address.

I found and followed the advice in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173913/strange-network-issue-works-on-windows-but-not-on-ubuntu-works-on-campus-wire), especially because, upon reading it, I am pretty sure I'd shut down while I was logged in to a VPN earlier yesterday.  And in fact, I did have a /etc/resolv.conf file.  However, I was able to get on to my home network last night, so in retrospect, I guess this is not the issue.

However I followed it (I deleted the file) but it did not resolve my problem.  I rebooted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by running

sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf

I found it [in this thread on Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2227955)

That is the only thing I did in that thread (listed as step 2).  FYI I am not sure what it did, I compared output from nm-tool and from ifconfig from before I ran this (when it wasn't working) and after; I could not find anything different other than the 'Capabilities', where it lists the speed; the 'before' was 24 Mb/s, the 'after' was 48.  I doubt that fixed it, so I am wondering what the dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf does.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping 8.8.8.8 and receive a response but cannot ping google.com then it is most likely a DNS issue.

Can you ping your dns server? If not, try using 4.4.4.2 for DNS.

I am guessing you triple checked your ifconfig settings vs your ipconfig settings in Ubuntu vs Windows respectively and they match?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are using ubuntu 14.04 so do the following steps to correct the problem

1.Go to "Additional Divers"

2.Install driver from there.

3.Restart your system

4.Now your wifi will definitely work and it will show the wifi signals(within its range) also.

Regards

Inderjeet Vashista