# Fresh Ubuntu 16.04 Install no internet (wireless nor wired)

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, wired

I had Ubuntu 16.04 LTS single boot installed on my system for a couple months but yesterday for seemingly no reason (no updates or upgrades were performed) I lost internet connections. More specifically, I cannot browse or ping anything even though my computer says I’m connected to the internet. Since then I’ve re-installed Ubuntu 16 (first by reinstalling from a drive, then by deleting old OS then installing from a drive), and both times I’m still left without internet. Please help!! Here’s some more informatation. Keep in mind I’m writing this from my phone so info will be consice maybe too consice. Feel free to ask me to elaborate. Almost forgot to mention: other devices using the wireless connection have internet access.

Ping:I can ping my router IP address. But I cannot ping my gateway/dns (all packets lost). Occasionally 8.8.8.8 gets a response when I first connect via WiFi or wired (97% packet loss) but then it stops (100% packet loss). I can ping localhost all the time.

My ifconfig file list 3 default devices, eno1, lo, wlo1, which I believe is standard. When I connect to WiFi the wlo1 displays my router info (though Link encap says Ethernet. Not sure if that’s a problem). When make a wired connection with my phone as a tether eno1 is not used. Instead another device pops up (enp0sxxxxxxxx). It list my phones info.

/etc/network/interfaces
Only list:
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
Nothing else.

I’m not sure what else y’all will need (or need elaborated), but I’ll appreciate any help I can be given. I’ve searched far and wide and have tried many fixes to no avail. But this is a fresh install and am willing to try anything y’all suggest to get to the bottom of this. Thanks in advance!

(Please remember it’s hrd for me to display outputs here and that I have no internet connection to help remedy the problem)

Comment: Did you connect via LAN or wifi ?

Comment: I think issue lies in network manager. There were some issues in Ubuntu 16.04. I had similar issues with LAN. I suggest you to try/ install Ubuntu 16.04.3.  You can boot OS on live mode and check it.

Comment: I’m connected via WiFi. And also testing connection via my phone tether. Neither work. Is there a reason why my internet connection would work for so long and then all of a sudden stop?

Comment: (To further clarify), it’s says I’m connected through both of my previously mentioned connections but I have not internet access. Occasionally, using the tether and using WiFi, I get a returned packet when I ping, but I lose almost everything else. Most times I never get a returned packet. The whole time my computer says I’m connected to the internet

Comment: Do you use a VPN service by chance ? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/164342/internet-connection-not-working-although-it-says-it-is-connected

Answer (score 1):

So my ultimate fix was to connect to an internet source using eno1 aka using an ethernet instead of tethering my phone. Once connected I did as sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade.

After this I decided to start trying some of the fixes I had tried before and the first one I tried worked, namely: on the IPv6 setting, set the method to ignore.

You go to setting > network > wireless.
Click settings on the bottom left description card of your router. Go to the IPv6 tab and set method to ignore.

After a reboot my wireless was up and running. Thanks all.