# Suddely internet is not accessible

Tags: networking, firefox, internet, thunderbird, dns

I am going crazy here. One day everything was working fine. I turned pc off and went to sleep. Next day turn pc on and cannot access internet (from any browser).

The situation is: I cannot open any webpage from browser (tried Firefox and Epiphany) and cannot receive emails in thunderbird. BUT if I run firefox from console as sudo, I can use it as usual. I can access Skype and pretty much any other network stuff (like installing software with apt-get etc.), also if I use Astrill VPN software I can access webpages even running without sudo.

I haven't install any software or anything like that for several days = I have not a clue what could cause this. Just by the way, other Win PC in our home has no issue.

Here is what I have tried to fix this:

- I have tried to restart my pc, router, modem - multiple times
- I have tried to change permissions to my firefox profile
- I have tried to completely re-install firefox and start with blank profile, thus no addons
- I have tried to change /etc/resolv.conf to an IP of my router (it was 127.0.1.1)
- I have tried to change my hostname (from tomino-NB to tominoNB)

I think I might try even more stuff. None of it works.

Can someone please try to help me.
Thank you

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tried this: [Removing resolv.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142327/can-not-access-internet-dns-names-do-not-resolve-after-update-today?rq=1) - Didn't help
Also "ping" and "dig" commands cannot resolve host

**UPDATE 2:**

I have tried to edit nameservers in resolv.conf but still no effect. 
I can ping router as well as I can ping outside IP. So definitely just some DNS issue. Is it possible that something is rewriting path to resolv.conf and using different file?

**UPDATE 3:**

I have just restarted PC and everything works now... resolv.conf went back to nameserver 127.0.1.1 . I have no clue what happened that it works again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Firefox or Ubuntu specific problem. To me it seems to be a DNS problem. The information you provide assumes it is a software problem (which I think it is not). Since you use the abbreviation NB I guess you have a notebook and you have traveled between different networks... this can cause a change in the DNS resolving information. But to be sure, can you ping your router and/or an outside IP address?

BTW, resolv.conf should contain your DNS information, not your local router (only if it runs a DNS caching daemon) or localhost:

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Note: you can add these entries, but they are not always optimal as these are provided by Google. Use the one provided by your ISP if possible.

Could you try opening a page by using the IP address: e.g. 173.194.37.65 for one of Google. And if not, can you ping it at least. A traceroute would be better.

Note:
User was able to connect to outside webpages using the IP address, so confirmed it was a DNS problem. Eventually adding the entries to DNS and a restart of the notebook made it work. I suspect he messed up his networkstack since he also used Astrill. A problem I have also encountered on Fedora many times (ld_preload maybe the cause?). At least it works for him ATM.

Comment: I have tried different nameservers, still nothing. I updated the question check it out

Comment: User contacted me by email; problem seems to be resolved.