# 14.04 Resolving Host (DNS) Problem

Tags: networking, dns, intel-wireless

UPDATE: Problem solved with 16.04.

I have an Asus Zenbook UX32V. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and now I cannot browse the Internet. When I connect to a wireless network everything is fine for 2-3 minutes and the browser (Chrome or Firefox) stops opening web pages. But torrent, skype and whatsapp web (if started before the problem began) works fine. My phone and windows computer can go online too. If I disable and re-enable networking, I can open web pages for another 2-3 minutes and problem repeats.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

outputs:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088e] (rev 24)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 AGN [8086:4060]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I tried these:

- Switch to Google public DNS.
- Delete the connection from the Network Manager and create a new one.
- Wicd network manager
- Comment out `dns=dnsmasq` in `NetworkManager.conf` file (https://askubuntu.com/a/432374/411641)
- Removed `resolv.conf` (https://askubuntu.com/a/142342/411641)
- Disabled 11n `iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1996768)
- Disabled wlan0 power management (https://askubuntu.com/a/85223/411641)
- Changed `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file to

  ```
   options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 swcrypto=1 11n_disable=8
  ```

  (http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/322-ubuntu-trusty-intel-centrino-6235-slow-freeze)

None of them worked. Because I messed with a lot of settings in different combinations, I formatted the computer and installed Ubuntu all over again.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`

Comment: Have you tried another wireless connections (like public wifi in cafe...)?

Comment: Can you open IP addresses in your browser instead of URLs after it crashed? Try `109.193.193.109` which is one of the IPs that `google.com` uses. You can also try the tool `nslookup`, which allows you to resolve URLs to IP addresses. You can change the DNS server it uses with the interactive command `server 8.8.8.8` for google's DNS for example.

Comment: @Byte Commander I cannot ping 109.193.193.109 or 8.8.8.8 dns server.

Comment: Maybe it is problem with torrents. If in your torrent-client are allowed to many connections it can slow down networking in the whole system. Please post preferences of your torrent here.

Comment: I know you edited that you've returned to Windows, but can you confirm network properly functioning on the same PC?

Comment: @UNIm95 Even if I close the torrent client, I still cannot open pages in browsers. Problem begins even before I install a torrent client after a fresh install.

Comment: @Oxwivi Networking is fine in the same computer for almost a day now.

Comment: @brifbraff Then it's more than likely it's a driver issue. File a bug report, you must.

Comment: Would you consider updating to 15.10? Or using the 15.10 live CD to see if that fixes it?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf` and `ls -la /etc/dnsmasq.d/`

Comment: does your module match your hardware? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2178006

Comment: can you post the out put of this trace command.  "traceroute 8.8.8.8"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is one of 3 things.  It's either a hardware/device issue, a networking stack issue, or a DNS issue.
The hardest to identify is a device issue, so lets consider that last.

The easiest to diagnose is a networking issue.  During an outage: Try running ifconfig in a console.  It should show a configured device with an IP address.  At the very least you should be able to ping that, thus you can generate packets.
Run `route` to see what your default Gateway is, and try pinging that.  If there is no default gateway, or you can't ping the default gateway, that's your problem there.  If you can, then try pinging 109.193.193.109 and if that fails (ICMP echo could be blocked on your network, like it is on mine), try visiting http://109.193.193.109 in a browser.  If that works, it's most likely a DNS issue.

DNS Issues:  Try or ping www.google.co.uk (if dnsutils isn't installed).  It should present an IP address.  In my case it's 216.58.219.99.  If it doesn't, you'll need nslookup/dig (from the dnsutils package) to diagnose.  nslookup will tell you the Server Address, and hence tell you which DNS server is supposedly serving your requests.  If it's not working, you may have a badly configured system, or a broken DNS server.  I would suggest you try installing a local DNS server (install package bind9 and setup 127.0.0.1 as your DNS server), or try re-configuring NetworkManager.  I've found it nothing but trouble.

As for device issues. If the appropriate device appears in ifconfig , then it's probably not going to be a device problem that you can fix, but judging from what you said above, I doubt it's a device problem, unless it's as silly as a bad cable/connector in your computer/router, but I have had issues with the Raspberry Pi, which turned out to be sufficient power on the board to run the device and detect it, but not enough to interrogate (running ifconfig resulted in a device failure).