# Unable to use internet in ubuntu

Tags: proxy

It is actually weird that I am unable to connect to the internet, earlier I was using a proxy network and I had configured proxy everywhere and now that I want to connect to a network without proxy I am unable to connect using both Mozilla and chrome browser. I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried changing proxy to no proxy in settings and restarted my system but it doesn't help. And connecting to the same network using windows I can use the internet.
This is really weird, please someone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is within your proxy settings. I've had this issue.

Try disabling  the proxy completely in the system. I mean the firefox has specific proxy settings. Try disabling that. Also disable proxy in your system settings.

For chrome try this in terminal for open with disabled proxy:

```
google-chrome --no-proxy-server
```

Try pinging in terminal to check connection:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

**Edit:**
From the [Discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84414/discussion-between-ll-and-adil-saju). It is figured out that that problem is with the DNS configuration in the linux system. Enter this:

```
sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/backup.resolv.conf
```

This would solve the problem.
References: 
[1](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1735863/ping-browse.html)
[2](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/02/08/find-out-why-you-cant-access-a-website-or-service-on-the-internet/)
[3](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/no-ping-on-connected-internet-in-archlinux-4175592131/)
[4](https://superuser.com/questions/392179/why-cant-my-browser-resolve-host-but-ping-and-nslookup-can)
[5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142327/can-not-access-internet-dns-names-do-not-resolve-after-update-today)

Comment: I have tried both the options doesn't work

Comment: can you give more details on your network and connection.

Comment: problem can be with your browser too. try pinging via terminal:   `ping google.com` to check your network connection

Comment: google-chrome --no-proxy-server doesnt work and ping google.com says google.com: Name or service not known

Comment: Can you be olease more specific on what details you need?

Comment: sorry that's cos google's not in your dns. try pinging `ping 8.8.8.8` for checking network connection. If that worked, the problem can be fixed with settings.

Comment: I cant post screenshot, it outputs like PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=118 time= 273ms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84414/discussion-between-ll-and-adil-saju).